# I am trying to use center widget in flutter, but due to some unknown reason it is not working, please help me

Tags: android, flutter

I have recently started learning flutter and got stuck at my very first basic hello world application:/
So, basically I am trying to center the entire content on the screen using the center tag, but it is not working, it would be really helpful if someone looks into my problem and helps me:)

**Here's the code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Center(child: Text('Hello World'))));
}
```

The application screen:

[image: The application screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
           child: Text('Hello World')
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

`Text` needs an ancestor of `Material` to be rendered "correctly" and since `Scaffold` has one, it'll work fine.

Comment: Thankyou for replying:) It gives error **The named parameter 'child' isn't defined**

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer use, use `body` instead. @YashVishwakarma

Comment: Yep, it worked brother!

Comment: Kindly upvote, thanks.